# Regular Expression String

Tags: regex

I just after some help constructing a regular expression check on the following sequence in C#. I need to ensure the value entered matches the following format.

NNNNCCCCCCCCNNNNNNN

2000AAAAAAAA0001001

[image]

Thanks for any help on this

Brendan

Comment: You have two group of A-Z and Digits (3, 4), what is their difference? Can I assume [4 Digits][A-Z][7 Digits]?

Comment: What software did you use to draw the diagram?

Comment: I use FastStone Capture. I have for years to help capture screens from my desktop. It has a simple built in image editor.
Brilliant software for a small price. Cant recommend it highly enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [0-9]{4}[A-Z]{4}[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}
```

If you want to be able to grab each set as a group for processing you need to add ( ) around each pattern.

```
 ([[0-9]{4})([A-Z]{4})([A-Z]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{3})
```

This will allow you to recover each set of characters from the match without having to re-parse the string again. If you need that.

Oh and if the first set of digits cannot start with a zero

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}[A-Z]{4}[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: OOPS did not pay enough attention this is for C# :).. fixing it.

Comment: If you want to allow lower-case letters, use small `z`s instead of big `Z`s. Also, does C# allow `\d` in place of `[0-9]` like Ruby does?